# Is the following C++ casting correct?

Tags: c++, casting

I read a few posts on the usage of static and dynamic casts specifically from [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-staticcast-dynamiccast-and-reinterpretcast-be-used)

I have a doubt regarding the usage of cast in the following manner. Can someone verify the below mentioned code:-

This is upward casting in inheritance hierarchy

```
template<class Base, class Derived>

inline Handle<Base> STATIC_CAST(Handle<Derived> hd) {

  Handle<Base> hb;

  Derived* dp = hd.get(); // Assume this gives pointer of derived class object

  Base* bp = static_cast<Base*> (dp);

  if(bp) {

     hb = Ptr2Handle(bp); // Assume this give reference to Handle 

  }

  return hb;

}
```

*Derived is actually the derived class from class Base.

What about downward casting in the following code?

```
template<class Base, class Derived>

inline Handle<Derived> DYNAMIC_CAST(Handle<Base> hb) {

  Handle<Derived> hd;

  Base* bp = hb.get();

  Derived* dp = dynamic_cast<Derived*> (bp);

  if(dp) {

     hd = Ptr2Handle(dp);

  }

  return hd;

}
```

What will be the impact if the above two MACROS are passed with Base and Derived class swapped?

Comment: are base and derived related types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Base` is really a base class of `Derived`, there's absolutely no need for any cast, meaning that `static_cast` in the above code is absolutely superfluous. It doesn't achieve anything a mere assignment wouldn't do implicitly. Moreover, in upcasts (from derived to base), `dynamic_cast` is absolutely equivalent to `static_cast`, meaning that `dynamic_cast` wouldn't achieve anything new either.

Actually, by placing an explicit `static_cast` cast in that code, its author enabled forceful "reverse" casts (downcasts). I.e. you can use this code to cast from base classes to derived classes. I don't know whether this was the intent (I doubt it was, judging by the template parameter names), and if it wasn't it might be a good idea to remove the cast entirely, since it is dangerous.

If, despite my doubts, the code was actually supposed to support downcasts, then `dynamic_cast` might indeed help to catch potential errors. However, keep in mind that `dynamic_cast` works in downcasts with polymorphic class types only.

Comment: yes..that will be fun, if somebody passes Derived class for the parameter Base and Base for the parameter Derived.

Comment: The impact is that if `Derived` is really derived from `Base`, you can pass them in reverse (derived as base and base as derived), and the function will say nothing - it will just quietly do an unchecked downcasts. If it turns out that the `Base` pointer is not really pointing to a `Derived` instance, the result of that downcast will be meaningless. Yet, your function will say nothing. If you intended your function for upcasts only, don't do any explicit casts in it.

Answer (score 0):

A static_cast upward (in direction of ancestors) in hierarchy is always legal. That cast will be legal (assuming Base and Derived are classes) iff Base is a base class of Derived.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Derived` is derived from `Base` the cast although correct is unnecessary. You can directly assign the result of `hd.get()` to `Base*`